# Javascript replace() - Exclude the $1 from the replace rule

Tags: javascript

how can i exclude the $1 from the replace rule?

```
regex = new RegExp('hallo, test, blub', 'gi');


content = content.replace(regex,'<strong>$1</strong>');

alert('$1'); // dont work
```

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: You need to elaborate more on the question. What do you want to actually replace. Give a few examples of the input, and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$1` refers to the first group captured by the regex and is available only in the replacement string.

For example, if content is `The score is 234` and the regex is `score is (\d+)`, it will be replaced as `<strong>234</strong>`.

If you want the value, you can use `content.match(regex)[1]`.

```
var c = "asd 123";
var r = /[a-z]+\s+(\d+)/;
var match = c.match(r);
if(match)
    console.log(match[1]);
else
    console.log("no match");
```

Comment: In the JS method, you can also specify a function instead of the replacement string. Within that function you can assign the matching string(s) to a variable and use it after the replace (see http://jsfiddle.net/Nzkrk/ for example. I'm not sure when this was introduced to JS and I've never found any documentation on it, but it is supported in every browser I've tested.

Comment: @Andrew That's required only if you're replacing. If all you want is to get the substring, you needn't use a replace callback for that.

Answer (score 0):

$1 only applies in the second argument to `replace()` and doesn't exist outside of that line of code. If you strictly need to get your hands on the match string, you *could* however do something like:

```
var dollar1;
content = content.replace(regex, function(s, p1) {
  dollar1 = p1;
  return '<strong>' + p1 + '</strong>';
});
alert(dollar1);
```